# Customize the (about:home) page in google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, customization

I want to know if its possible to customize the way your default google chrome look locally on your computer. I am talking from a developer's point of view and not user(ie not to change the home page by going into chrome setting).
I can change the UI by using the chrome f12 option locally. As chrome is installed on my machine then there should be an index.html or something alike file present to render chrome as it does. I want to access that file if possible. 
Thanks

Comment: Im going to guess the common solution is an extension

Comment: any options for such extensions?During my search could not find any relative.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/developing-google-chrome-extensions--net-33076 scroll down to the new tab part..Guessing this can be adapted to default home page as there are many extensions which give you a custom home page. Otherwise it will be ol fashion searching the base docs https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview

Comment: Apart from extensions, is there any method to customize the files already present in the setup docs for google chrome?

Answer (score 1):

you might be able to find some various files, so i would suggest looking through the following folder. `C:\Users\MYUSERNAMEHERE\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

or `C:\Users\MYUSERNAMEHERE\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\` as these are the ones that contain your chrome installation, there maybe another folder but this is always the one i have used when developing extensions..

Otherwise i think you will be stuck with the extension part, i myself would have a look at this if you really need.. But that could be a week before i get the chance.

If your looking to deploy a custom google chrome, so they dont need to install extensions. Try the following google term: `deploy custom chrome`

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions

But editing it directly with just finding a single html file / style i dont think is as easy as it would need to load certain objects into memory and i think they are a little more complex than a plain text file.

**EDIT - Looks Like Its Extension Only Now**
Had 5 minutes and did a quick google, there was a point where you could use custom style sheets for v32 and below but that was removed https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=234007&view=revision

So you either need to work with firefox or build an extension.. I could not see any files/folders that would do what you need. So yea i'd start looking at extensions.

Comment: Thanks @Mayhem for the info. I was able to edit the about:home page in firefox by editing the omni.ja file. I agree with you on the not simple html thing with chrome, but still there must be an option without extension I hope.

Comment: Have a look at my edit, Honestly with someone like google.. They will trial certain ideas and the determine what is better for the end user.. In this case they went with pure extensions so people would know where a modification has been done.. If this has been helpful, do feel free to mark as correct answer... Also using extensions is a clean solution and one i would recommend vs editing files per install